# ./source/vstoxx_data_31032014.h5`` does not exist

Tags: python, finance

I am using ipython to compile my code, but I am faced with an error.

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
h5=pd.HDFStore('./source/vstoxx_data_31032014.h5','r')
futures_data=h5['futures_data']
options_data=h5['options_data']
h5.close()
```

And the OS error is:

> OS error ./source/vstoxx_data_31032014.h5`` does not exist

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: well the error is quite clear: you are not pointing to the right path of the file you are trying to open.

Comment: I copy this code from my textbook,I do not know how to solve it.I have download the script"vstoxx_data_31032014.h5"from github.But I have nothing to do with

Comment: `vstoxx_data_31032014.h5` is just a file. So, since you have downloaded it then you should put it in the same working directory as the directory where you're initializing your `ipython` session and change your code to say `h5=pd.HDFStore('vstoxx_data_31032014.h5','r')` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can check present directory using:

```
%pwd
```

If the output of the above is any different from where you have save the downloaded file, then you can copy the downloaded file to this location. That way, the command will start reading the file.

Alternatively if copy paste of the desired file is not feasible, then directory can also be changed using the following function:

```
os.chdir(path)
```